# Filter into Foreign Keys on Django-Rest Datatables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, datatables

I have a datatable for `Order` model which contains some fields from `User` model and is implemented using serializer as following

**serializers.py**

```
# customer order detail serializer
class CustomerOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.last_name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        remove_fields = kwargs.pop('remove_fields', None)
        super(CustomerOrderSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if remove_fields:
            for field_name in remove_fields:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'amount', 'order_status', 'created', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        read_only_fields = ['issue_date', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

In **views.py**

```
class OrderList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = CustomerOrderSerializer
```

I am successfully able to get `first_name` & `last_name` fields as in datatable format as shown

[image]

However, **my requirements** is to filter/search in datatable on fields `first_name` & `last_name` which are from different model `User`

when I try to filter on those fields I get **Following error**:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'first_name' into field. Choices are: ..., .., ..., ..
```

Can anyone help me understand, **How we can filter on foreign key fields in django-rest datatables**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SearchFilter`.[doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter)

```py
from rest_framework import filters

class OrderList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = CustomerOrderSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['user__first_name', 'user__last_name']
```

After that, you can search first name & last name by ?search=foo query parameter.